# Text is overwritten while writing in DataGridViewCell

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I'm working on a Winform application. I have a DataGridView. When I write the first character in Cell, cursor automatically focuses on the first character. If I write a second character, it overwrites the first character.

Thus if I need to write more characters, every time I have to press Right Arrow key to move. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your code so we can see what's going on?

Comment: By any chance, have you forgot the insert key enabled while testing that?

Comment: No,i am sure that Insert Key Is not pressed..